# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\Locale::handle() | Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

when I try to insert the third parameter in the handle method, I get the following error:

```
'Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\Locale::handle(), 2 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/weather-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 167 and exactly 3 expected'
```

How can I fix it?

My middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Services\SettingsService;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Locale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  SettingsService $settingsService
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, SettingsService $settingsService): mixed
    {
        $locale = $settingsService->get('language', app()->getLocale());
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel:

```
'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the `SettingsService $settingsService` into your `__construct()`.

```php
class Locale
{
  private SettingsService $settingsService;

  public function __construct(SettingsService $settingsService)
  {
    $this->settingsService = $settingsService;
  }

  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
  {
    // access via $this->settingsService
  }
}
```

The `handle` method only accepts two parameters. So use the constructor injection to solve this problem.